# Is there a faster way to perform a weighted average over a vector than using brute force?

Tags: c++, animation, vector, average

So, I'm implementing skeletal animations, one part of which  is to be able to blend several frames together (either for interpolation, or blending together different animations). Each of my frames is represented as a set of `AnimationFrameData`:

```
struct AnimationFrameData {

/// @brief Indexed by index of joint in skeleton
std::vector<Vector3> m_translations;
std::vector<Quaternion> m_rotations;
std::vector<Vector3> m_scales;

};
```

Then, to blend an arbitrary number of frames together, I use what I call a `BlendSet`:

```
struct BlendSet {
    std::vector<std::vector<Vector3>> m_translations;
    std::vector<std::vector<Quaternion>> m_rotations;
    std::vector<std::vector<Vector3>> m_scales;
};
```

For each member of Blendset, the entries of the outer vector represent the nodes of the skeletal hierarchy, each of which has a vector of either translations, rotations, or scale factors from each of the animations that are to be blended together. Each animation also has a corresponding "blend weight" that is used to perform the weighted average. Once the average is performed over each sub-vector, I end up with a final `AnimationFrameData` for the final resulting animation.

Besides being a bit hard to keep track of, I'm wondering if this approach is lacking in performance. It's "fast enough" for just one animation playing, but I don't think it will scale. Is there a more efficient and elegant way to perform this averaging?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<Vector3>> m_translations;` -- You may want to make this and all of those other vectors a single vector instead of a `std::vector<std::vector<>>`.

Comment: I was thinking that. It would require a knowledge of the number of animations before-hand so I could give the vectors the correct size and stride, but it'll save me an entire sub-loop, so I think it's the way to go.

Comment: Also, there is more potential for cache-friendliness, since a single vector's data is stored in contiguous memory.